# Split Foreach Into Different Sections

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of profiles. I want to loop through them and print out the data for each person. I'm using bootstrap so I'd like to have 3 profiles per row and then start a new row for another 3 profiles, like the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        Profile Data
    </div>
</div>
```

If I loop through using foreach, I'll get a new row each profile, when I'd like 3 profiles and then a new row:

```
foreach($profiles as $p){
    echo '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            '.$p->name.'
        </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: Use a counter within the loop and only echo the row start div when the counter is 1 and the row end div when the counter is 3. Reset counter back to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put some basic logic for three results per row:

```
echo '<div class="row">';
$count = 0;
foreach ($profiles as $p) {
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . $p->name . '</div>';
    $count++;
    if($count%3==0){
        print '</div><div class="row">';
        $count = 0;
    }
}
echo '</div>'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($profiles as $p){
  $i++;
  if( ($i)% 3 == 0 ){
    echo '<div class="row">';
  }
  echo  '<div class="col-md-3">'.$p->name.'</div>';
  if( ($i)% 3 == 0 ){
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Your dividing logic by modulus is wrong, must be `$i%3==0` otherwhise will produce incorrect structure. And is not necessary to check it twice. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php